# Finding a plane equation given a distance and a point.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

I've got a question that I can't seem to figure out, any hint/help would be appreciated.

Be $L$ a line, and $P_1$ a point.

So, I've got $P_1$, and $L$, I know the distance from $P_1$ and $L$, let it be $c$, so I need to find the equation of a plane that has $P_1$ and also the distance  is $c$.

My take on it is to find a plane that is to find the perpendicular vector of $L$ in respect of $P_1$, let that be the normal of the plane, and carry from there.

Comment: What are $L$ and $P_1$?

Comment: L is a line, P a point, sorry about that, just corrected.

Comment: It is still unclear what you mean about a line $L$ and a point $P_1$. Is $L$ a parametrization of a line lying in the plane to be determined? The same goes for $P_1$, does it lie in the plane?

Comment: No, $L$ is any line, and $P_1$ is any point, $P_1$ is not on $L$ and I know the distance between the both of them is $c$, with that, I need to find the equation of a plane such that the distance from the plane to $L$ is $c$ and $P_1$ belongs to said plane.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is meant by the distance $c$? I presume the point $P_1$ is fixed, but the line $L$ extends infinitely, so the distance would not be a constant, but rather a variable representing the distance between the fixed point $P_1$ and any point on the line.

Comment: $c$ would be the shortest distance from $P_1$ to $L$, that would be the length of a perpendicular line from $P_1$ to $L$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the problem correctly by the discussion we had in the comments:

Let $\mathbf{x_0}$ and $\mathbf{x_1}$ be two points on your line $L$. You can express the [shortest distance between any point $\mathbf{P}$ and this line by](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html):

$$
d = \frac{|(\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2) \times (\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{P})|}{|\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2|}
$$

By using $\mathbf{P}_1\mathbf{P} = (p_1 - x, p_2 - y, p_3 - z)$ as your point, and setting $d$ equal to the distance $c$, you have an equation for a plane satisfying your problem.